# How can I protect a laptop with the lid opened during a car ride

Tags: laptop, lenovo-laptop

My Lenovo laptop hinge is broken, and hence I can't close the lid. The laptop will remain "opened" for now, until I get the lid fixed.

I need to travel with it in a car, it's a long journey travel, and I can't hold it throughout the ride, the most I can do is to put it at the car floor.  A laptop with the lid opened which is put on the floor can easily move around when the car accelerates or deaccelerates, and it might smashed into the back of front seats. Or the laptop can more easily bounce up and down because with the lid opened the center of gravity shifts up.

What I can do in order to protect the laptop so that it's still usable?

Comment: https://travel.stackexchange.com/ :This question is better suited here...

Comment: For clarity, what kind of problems do you think may occur because the laptop is open?

Comment: @Anaksunaman,  laptop with the lid opened which is put on the floor can easily move around when the car accelerates or deaccelerates.

Comment: @Anaksunaman, the laptop can more easily bounce up and down because with the lid opened the center of gravity shifts up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put it in an appropriately sized box. Then stuff it with bubble wrap, packing foam or whatever you have at hand. The point is to make sure the screen won't move on its own and to protect it, along with the keyboard. The outer shell doesn't need extra protection, but has to be padded too to keep the hinge static.

You may be tempted to orient the laptop screen down. I would recommend against this because it will put more strain on the broken hinge. Keep it in the normal orientation.

If the box doesn't seem stable enough for a safe ride, use a larger one.

Packing other stuff in the same box shouldn't be a problem if the laptop is stuffed securely. Nesting boxes is also an option.

Answer (score 0):

If the opening angle is the same as that of the seat, leave it on either the back seat or passenger seat and lock it in with the seat belt.

Since the screen is against the back of the seat and held by the seat belt, it won't bounce that much.